# Azure Execute SQL Query Connector Not Showing Actual Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[ExecuteSQLQueryConnectorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyglN.jpg)

we are using Execute SQL Query Connector in Azure LogicApp to update data for record. However after where clause on adding formal parameters(datatype) it is not showing Text field to give actual parameters(value)
Here is inner code view :

```
"body": {
    "formalParameters": {
        "shipment": "nvarchar(20)"
    },
    "query": "UPDATE  [dbo].[fsOutboundShipmentStaging] SET TRANSFERSTATUS = 3 \nWHERE SHIPMENTID = @shipment\n"
},
```

On running LogicApp like this getting following error :

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "logic-apis-southcentralus.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 502,
      "message": "Must declare the scalar variable \"@shipment\".\r\n",
      "source": "sql-logic-cp-southcentralus.logic-ase-southcentralus.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
  }
}`

Thanks for help...

Comment: The resultsets SHIPMENT is the array attribute. So, it will be forced to use `for each` to get its vaule one by one. If the query result only in a JSON object, the snapshot will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

> However after where clause on adding formal parameters(datatype) it is not showing Text field to give actual parameters(value)

Adding formal parameters, which means you **set up the parameter's datatype**. Then you could set the actual value to the parameter in `query` line.

You could refer to the working flow to me as below:

[image]

And the code view is as below:
[image]